Calculating power and energy of a surge waveform
As far as I know, to determine if a Surge Protection Device (SPD) is suitable for a specific scenario, it must be capable of handling the energy of the surge for the duration of that surge.
I want to calculate energy of surge waveforms if I know its rise time, pulse width (time to 50%), peak amplitude and I also have an equation for the surge waveform.
Does anybody have an idea about how should I approach this?
It would be helpful if I can get some mathematical formulae.


Does anybody have an idea about how should I approach this ?

I've used a circuit simulation tool for this and got results that proved to be acceptable when a real surge test was performed. It was a simulation of parallel  SPDs handling the current and energy from a 2 kV indirect lightning surge to EN 61000-4-5.
I used microcap as simulator but I expect LTspice would work just as well.

You may find ISO 7637-2's calculation method handy (Annex E, p.30):

The surrounding text describes the double-exponential pulse (i.e., exponential rise, exponential fall), showing the math behind the answer (the simple integration of an exponential curve).
This will be less true for a more rounded curve as IEC 61000-4-5 uses, where the 2nd-order exponential response is evident (depending on whether the exact waveform is 8/20, 1.2/50µs, or anything inbetween), and a different integration is required.
This all goes out the window when a nonlinear device, such as an SPD, is involved.  The energy absorbed is largely towards the peak, but the voltage during the peak is held mostly stable, and the energy deposited can be less than an equivalent load resistance might absorb.
A user might also define energy as the initial energy in the generator network; at least at a glance, I don't see
I don't know what standards are used by SPD manufacturers to measure energy; such standards are largely irrelevant outside of actual manufacturers of such products.  (Largely, but not wholly. It would be informative to know how they test and rate these things, and it's a shame such information is not freely available.  But, the information within such standards is really most useful when you're actually in the business of making and selling the things.)  If you have a pressing need, you might look at IEC 61051-1, IEC 61643-331, UL 1449 or others.
Other than that, I would hazard a guess that they measure the device in a standard test jig (may be in-house standard), while monitoring current through and voltage across the device; the integral product gives deposited energy.
A simpler method is to simulate it.  A typical IEC 61000-4-5 combined wave generator network is:

(2096 is the initial voltage on the capacitor, for a 2kV output pulse.)  This can easily be combined with MOV, TVS and other models provided by manufacturers to evaluate performance.
